# cakephp cache folder not writable on iis

Tags: php, iis, cakephp

Cakephp is saying my cache folder is not writable. Ive had a look and IIS DOES have write permissions on the folder.

```
Warning (512): C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\tmp\cache\ is not writable [CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 267]
```

Comment: Have you tried giving Full Control to Everyone for the /tmp folder (and all child files/folders)?

Comment: doing that fixes the problem. How can I pull back the perms now, to just allow IIS. Is it safe to allow Everyone full access to that folder.

Comment: It should be perfectly safe, if your document root is `app/webroot/`, which IIRC it should be with an IIS configuration. Moreover, nothing sensitive is stored in `app/tmp/`, even if it were exposed to the public. The typical Linux/UNIX setup is `chmod -R 0777 app/tmp/`, which is equivalent to Full Control for Everyone.

Comment: The document root, is /app/ but the web.config should rewrite to point to app/webroot/. Hypothetically speaking if /tmp/ were exposed to the public, would they be able to read the cached data? or change it?

Comment: Sure, but that implies a much more troubling misconfiguration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the user to which you've granted access is not the user through which PHP/IIS is accessing that folder.

A simple solution is to grant Full Control access to Everyone for that folder. This should be reasonably safe, as this folder is not publicly accessible except through more-troubling misconfigurations.

Alternatively, you can attempt to discern which user PHP is impersonating to access the filesystem, and grant Read/Write access to that user. The PHP documentation for [installation/configuration on IIS](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php) may be useful.

Comment: thanks. Using your link I found that IIS7 uses IUSR account for anonymous access. I gave IUSR write access to /tmp/ and it worked.

Comment: The command icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload /grant IUSR:(OI)(CI)(M)  did it for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to give read/write permissions to everyone on that folder and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because the cache folder was a file. I deleted the file and everything worked perfectly. I guess it got archived with an empty folder or something. I always wondered why the the empty file is inside of most empty folders, perhaps it prevents this problem.